# Django 3.2.8 | DetailView url doesn't load base.html if "/" present

Tags: django, django-urls

I have this weird behavior where the following loads static files :

url.py :

```
path('<int:pk>/detail', PropositionsDetailView.as_view(), name='propositions-detail')
```

but if I add a trailing "/" it doesn't seem to find them ; I only get the base.html unformated :

```
path('<int:pk>/detail/', PropositionsDetailView.as_view(), name='propositions-detail')
```

would someone know why that is ?

---

### edit (as per Iain Shelvington request) :

settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

base template structure :

```
myApp
 |
  templates
   |
   partials
    |
    base.html
```

html page :

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block contents %}
....
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you share your static files settings and the section of your template where you link to them?

Comment: just edited the content. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you add where you use static in your template? Where you load images/css/js. If the current path affects the loading of your static files then you may have an issue with how you generate the path/url